# Laravel 5 Pass the id from the DB to the <select> value

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to php frameworks and I'm using Laravel to create a CRUD application. The problem is that when I try to pass the Id of a category from DB to the  value from the View I get the error:

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\wamp\www\vecrud\resources\views\products\create.blade.php)

Controller

```
public function create()
{
    $products_create = categories::all()->lists('category');
    $categ_id = categories::all()->lists('id');

    return View::make('products.create', compact('products_create', 'categ_id'));
}
```

View

```
{!! Form::label('category', 'Categorie') !!} <br />
{!! Form::select('category', $products_create, Input::old('category'), array('value' => $categ_id)) !!}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value (`id`) and the text of the select option (`category`) should be in the same array. I suppose you are looking for this:

```
$category_list = categories::all()->lists('category', 'id');

return View::make('products.create', compact('category_list'));
```

View:

```
{!! Form::select('category', $category_list, Input::old('category')) !!}
```

---

Also you don't need to call `all()` before `lists()`:

```
$category_list = Categories::lists('category', 'id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `lists()` method, the first parameter is the array value, and the optional second parameter is the attribute to use for the array key. So if you want values from a database keyed by primary key, then you can do:

```
$options = $model->lists('name', 'id');
```

You can then just pass this array straight to the `select` form helper:

```
Form::select('name', $options, null, ['class' => 'form-control']);
```

Hope that helps!